# In C++, does dereferencing a nullptr itself cause undefined behaviour, or is it the acting upon the dereferenced pointer which is undefined?

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined-behavior

I happen to have a reason why I might want to dereference a nullptr.

Of course when I do, my program crashes, **and from what I gather,** this is due to the compiler playing it safe and stopping my program, rather than risking the program *acting* upon the dereferenced `nullptr`, which is undefined behaviour.

So my question is to affirm this:

1. Is it my compiler crashing my program, or the "undefined behaviour"?
2. If it is the compiler, suppose it didn't choose to crash the program, is the act of dereferencing the pointer in any way able to cause something to happen that could alter the behaviour of the program writ large? This is assuming that nothing is done to it at all, like so:

```cpp
void moot()
{
        QString *s{nullptr};
        *s;
}
```

2. **Continued:** Could I hypothetically run `moot()` thousands of times without any "undefined behaviour" taking place?
3. If true, what if I did not do anything to the object, but I did pass it around, like so:

```cpp
void receiveCC( QString         ) { return; }
void receiveR ( QString &       ) { return; }
void receiveCR( const QString & ) { return; }

void moot()
{
        QString *s{nullptr};
        *s;
        receiveCC(*s);
        receiveR (*s);
        receiveCR(*s);
}
```

3. **Continued:** Same as above; could such be done without any "Undefined behaviour" taking place?

Comment: As always with UB, anything can happen:  your program could crash, your program could work, your program could seem to work but corrupt memory.  Some people pretend that the universe might collapse or you could accidentally travel in time when UB happens, since U stands for undefined.  But these kind of questions should better be asked on StackOverflow, where a higher number of very skilled contributors will answer/criticize the answers.

Comment: The crash ***IS*** the effect of the undefined behaviour.

Comment: "Undefined behaviour" means the usually *"what will happen is not defined in the language specification"*. Still a specific combination of compiler, CPU, and operating system can show a very specific, defined behaviour - just don't expect it to be the same for a different combination of compiler, CPU, and operating system.

Comment: @DocBrown, unless the CPU, OR or compiler vendor chooses to document the behavior, even consistent behavior with a single set of compiler/OS/CPU should not be assumed when your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: I really hate it how I manage to ask questions that get downvoted, yet which get tons of upvoted answers.

Comment: People say there's no such thing as a dumb question.  But that's wrong.  Dumb questions are the most important ones.  You are dumb for not asking them.  People who hear them cringe, because they have to back up to fundamentals to answer them.   But if you don't ask and understand the answer, you will forever misunderstand the field, and once you do understand it, something important is easier.  People downvote dumb questions because they're too dumb to realize that the importance of the question outweighs their dislike of answering it fully.

Comment: Also, compilers don't crash the programs they compile.  They just generate code.  The code cant crash until you run it, and the compiler doesn't do that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the compiler that causes your program to crash on dereferencing a null pointer.   The problem is that the pointer is pointing to memory that it is illegal to reference, and the operating system kills your program for invalid behavior.

Trying to trick the compiler by obfuscating that it is a null pointer won't work, because it isn't the compiler that detects it.

There is no legitimate reason to dereference a null pointer unless you on a rare system that maps page zero (or you intend your program to crash).  It is generally accepted that zeroing a pointer is a good way to mark it as invalid and dereferencing an invalid pointer is a bug.  Modern operating systems do not give you a page of memory at that address specifically to make debugging invalid pointers easier.

I would not even call your program crashing from this to be undefined behavior.  Dereferencing a pointer with random data in it would give you undefined behavior.  Dereferencing a pointer that contains an address not assigned to your program is quite well defined in demand paged memory protected operating systems, and the behavior defined by the operating system is for your program to crash.  From the language's perspective, it is still undefined behavior, because what happens is not defined in the scope of the language.  Since this behavior is undefined by the language, the compiler can do nothing about it and should do nothing about it.

The exception to this is systems that have no memory protection and systems that intentionally map page zero.  Some older systems do this, but most of the modern systems that do are microcontrollers, some of which might even have memory mapped I/O or some other special purpose memory in page zero.

Since null pointer dereferences are typically bugs, it is unlikely a compiler would bother to optimize away null pointer dereferences or put guard code around a possible one, as this would not improve code performance. If they did even bother to detect this, they would do it to emit a warning to assist you in debugging, similar to the "code not reachable" warning.  The only reason for the compiler to generate different code around one would be if it knew what you were trying to do.

Comment: If dereferencing a null pointer in the programming language is actually translated to dereferencing a null pointer in the machine language, those specifics of the machine might be of interest. But as it is UB, it might be optimized away.

Comment: The null address is often dereferencable on microcontrollers that don't have a virtual address space/MMU/operating system. But dereferencing the null pointer in C/C++ is still UB. *Undefined behaviour* is a technical term in this context and can't be handwaved as in this answer.

Comment: @amon: Yes, UB is a technical term.  But it's not a magical word.  It has a specific meaning, and using that meaning is not "handwaving".

Comment: Unlikely? Just the opposite. UB is used as proof that code won't be executed / data won't have those values, and from that all that obviously useless and slow code will be eliminated. Remember: The fastest code is that which isn't there.

Comment: No.  Undefined behavior in code is a bug.  Compilers don't optimize bugs.  They warn you about them maybe, but if the code is going to crash, why optimize it?  Crash != slow.  If the compiler eliminates code that would change behavior, that would be a compiler bug.  The compiler's job is not to fix your bugs.  Warn you is nice, error out when it can, but not fix.

Comment: Undefined behavior is NOT proof code can't be executed.  It may not even be possible for the compiler to detect this situation -- you seem to think the compiler can solve the general halting problem.

Comment: Compilers have limited "reasoning"-ability about what code can do, especially in the face of limited information and limited processing-power. Thus, the compiler doesn't just optimize from the start of the program to the end, but also feeds back from points identified as "impossible" due to UB, to refine its understanding and eliminate useless code for impossible inputs. The compiler won't be perfect in spotting all opportunities either way.

Comment: Here's the problem with that.  The compiler can only optimize DEFINED behavior within the language.  It can't optimize undefined behavior, because it can't know what it is suppose to do, and anything it changes there might be wrong.  If it can sometimes "optimize" null pointer dereferences and sometimes not, that's going to be hell to debug.

Comment: @user10489 You are acting under the delusion that undefined behavior should mean anything specific. It doesn't, that's why it is called "undefined". Undefined Behavior itself isn't optimized (doing "anything at all" faster? Just do nothing, that is also in "anything at all"), but the fact that some path leads to UB is fed back into the optimizer, allowing it to disregard anything leading there. If the code is correct, that is a wonderful optimization. If it isn't, it just explodes differently. Sanitize-UB and similar options provided by some compilers define some of the UB to trap instead.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I'd be interested to know if you are aware of any compilers that optimize null pointer dereferences differently.  Your suppositions that it is useful to optimize it seems purely hypothetical to me, and contraindicated by discussions in the standards committees.

Comment: @user10489 Sometimes behaviour that is not defined by the language **is** defined by the compiler or the operating system.

Comment: @user253751: Yes, I said that, and was accused of hand waving.

Comment: @user253751 "whatever object code comes out" is tautologically defined, but it doesn't help with understanding why of all the things that the compiler *could* have done instead, it did what it did

Comment: Rather than the "compiler assumes that UB doesn't happen" you can have think of (the equivalent) model where "compiler *doesn't care* what happens during UB", and makes choices to optimise all the *other* code paths, which is fine under the "as-if" rule

Answer (score 9):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of what *Undefined Behavior* means.

Undefined Behavior is not something that is "caused" by your code. It is not something that happens. It is something that *is*.

If you have some piece of code somewhere that dereferences a null pointer, that is Undefined Behavior. UB gives the compiler a lot of leeway.

The way this is usually phrased is that the compiler is allowed to do *anything*. It is allowed to compile code that dereferences a null pointer into code that formats your hard disk. It is allowed to compile it into code that crashes. It is allowed to compile it into code that does random things. It is even allowed to compile it into code that *doesn't* crash.

And until a couple of years ago, that's mostly what compilers did. However, that isn't even the most dangerous part.

There is one thing the compiler is also allowed to do: because you are not allowed to write code that exhibits UB, the compiler is allowed to assume that there will be no UB, when optimizing your code. And because of the complex optimizations that modern compilers do, this can have very weird consequences.

Let's say you have an `if (userId == 0)` statement, where you have UB in the `else` part. Since you are not allowed to write code that exhibits UB, the compiler is allowed to assume that the `else` branch will never be taken. This means that the compiler is allowed to assume that `userId` will always be `0`, i.e. it is allowed to assume that the user is always root! And based on this assumption, it is allowed to optimize away other checks as well, opening you up to huge security holes.

This can lead to very extreme, or even worse, very subtle changes to the behavior of program parts far away from the place of the UB.

Comment: The funkiest thing is (virtual) time-travel though.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'd be wary of saying "funkiest". Inlining a function that is never called into `main` is quite funky

Comment: One of the documented reasons that the Standard left some actions as Undefined Behavior was to allow implementations to process various actions "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment" in cases where doing so might have useful effects not contemplated by the Standard, but without requiring that implementations slavishly do so even in cases that offer no benefit to their customers.  The Standard makes no effort to specify when compiler writers should presume that their customers might find such behavior useful, because compiler writers should know their customers' needs...

Comment: ...far better than the Committee ever could.  When the Standard says "non-portable or erroneous", that in no way excludes constructs that are non-portable but 100% correct on the kinds of implementations for which a program was designed.

Answer (score 6):

1. No, it’s your operating system (usually). Some (debug) compilers will insert guards for you, but it’s still the generated code not the compiler directly breaking.
2. Yes, undefined behavior means the compiler is free to do ***whatever*** it wants. Hypothetically, your compiler ***may*** generate code that ignores the null pointer dereference, or optimizes that code away. I **would not count on it.**
3. Again, as soon as you dereference it at all, your compiler may freely destroy the world and it’d be acceptable behavior.

Comment: With modern compilers, the worst part is that the compiler is allowed to assume that UB never happens, and it is allowed to make optimizations based on that assumption. With the powerful, far-reaching, complex, whole-program optimizations that modern compilers do, this can lead to very unexpected and hard to track down changes in program behavior far away from the actual site of the UB.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: The fact that a "Conforming C Implementation" may process a program a certain way in no way implies that a quality implementation which is designed to be suitable for any particular purpose could do such a thing.  The Standard deliberately allows implementations tailored to specialized purposes to process some constructs in ways that would render them unsuitable for most other purposes.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways an implementation might usefully process a statement like `*p = 0;` in circumstances where `p` might at least theoretically be null:

1. An implementation could interpret the pointer as a machine address and store 0 there, without regard for whether that pointer might be null, with whatever consequences result.  This may be useful on some platforms which have addressable storage or I/O registers at address zero, even if the compiler knows nothing about such storage or registers.  Further, on many other platforms, such treatment would force a program to terminate before anything worse could happen as a result of a pointer being unexpectedly null.
2. An implementation may check, before performing the store, that the pointer is not null, and force an abnormal program termination if the check fails, again preventing the code from doing anything worse.
3. An implementation might interpret the fact that the Standard would regard a null reference as Undefined Behavior as an invitation to infer that a program will never receive input that would result in a null dereference, and therefore any code which would only be relevant if such input were received may be omitted.  This may sometimes allow improved performance in cases where the program never receives any inputs that would lead to a null dereference, but may cause a program to process maliciously crafted input in an intolerably worse than useless fashion (such as allowing unauthorized remote code execution) under circumstances where the other means of processing the code would have resulted in the program being forcibly terminated before anything worse could happen.

The authors of the Standard expected that compiler writers would be better able to judge which course of action would best serve their customers than the Committee ever could.  It thus gives the compiler writers freedom to behave in any manner they see fit, on the presumption that anyone wishing to sell compilers to people whose code they would be processing would behave in whatever manner would best serve their customers, without needing the Standard to tell them how to do so.

Comment: GIGO still rules. Even if extra effort for a softer landing is sometimes appropriate and worth the cost and effort. Also, nobody ever said that C doesn't have plenty of sharp edges and hidden potholes.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Normal GIGO would accommodate the possibility that a program is supposed to process a variety of independent items, some of which are valid and some of which aren't, the portions of the output corresponding to valid items should be meaningful if the portions corresponding to invalid items would not be.  I certainly agree that extra effort for a "softer landing" is often appropriate, but a programmer would generally be better placed to make such judgments than a compiler writer.  If a "hard landing" from a segfault would  be a tolerable response to invalid input, but...

Comment: ...arbitrary code execution would not be, having a compiler process invalid input in a way that may allow arbitrary code execution unless programmers force it to include explicit null checks in the machine code would result in less efficient machine code than one which offers stronger behavioral guarantees, which is fed code that exploits such guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

It’s the dereferencing that causes undefined behaviour. And you may have to study the C++ Standard very carefully to see whether creating an l-value is already enough for undefined behaviour. Rules can be slightly different from C. For example, if int*p is a null pointer, then in C++ *p alone might not be enough to cause undefined behaviour, in C it definitely is.

Hardware and OS are quite irrelevant. Your code has either defined behaviour, then hardware and OS must be prevented from doing anything inappropriate, or your code has undefined behaviour, in which case letting the hardware / OS cause a crash is usually preferable to a silent failure, but is not required by the C++ standard.